# Acessar valor passado via parent::__construct()

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, construtor

Eu estou com dificuldades em pegar o valor passado via parent__construct em uma classe filha da Controller e utilizar esse valor em uma classe chamada View.

Ao realizar um var_dump na __Construct da classe Controller consigo recuperar o valor enviado da classe Form, mas quando tento recuperar esse mesmo valor em um MÉTODO dentro da classe View, ele aparece como null.

```
    /*=======================*/
    class Form extends Controller
    {
        //General builder of the WEB pages
        public function __construct()
        {
            //Redirecting the entire site for maintenance
            //redirect("/ops/maintenance");
    
            parent::__construct(__DIR__ . "/../../../themes/" . THEME . "/pages/");
        }

    /*=======================*/
    class controller
    {
        /** @var View */
        protected $view;
    
        /** @var Message */
        protected $message;
    
        //Builder extending classes
        /**
         * Controller constructor
         * @param string|null $pathToViews
         */
        public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
        {
            $this->view = new View($pathToViews);
            //the value passed in parent::__construct() appears here
            var_dump($pathToViews);
            $this->message = new Message();
        }
    }

    /*=======================*/
    //Class responsible for handling Views requests
    class view
    {
        protected $pathToViews;
    
        public function __construct(string $pathToViews = null)
        {
            $this->pathToViews = $pathToViews;
        }
    
        //Function to Load the View and send content from the backend to the frontend
        public function show($viewName, $data = [])
        {
            var_dump($this->pathToViews);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você está criando um objeto View e armazendando dentro da $view do controller. .. Você teria que acessá-lo $controller->view->show($viewName, $data ) não?

Comment: @WillKnippelberg

Na verdade não é isso, esses $viewName e $data não uso por agora, mas o que preciso acessar é o valor que envio pelo construtor da classe Form via parent__construct.

Sei que ele é recebido na classe pai Controller, pois realizo um degub na variavel $pathToViews.

Mas quando tento acessar esse conteudo da $pathToViews dentro do método show() ele vem como nulo

Comment: @WillKnippelberg já respondeu a sua dúvida. Na classe view ao invés de `var_dump` retorna o valor e depois chama `$controller->view->show($viewName, $data )`.